# Django querysets. How to prefetch only unique?

Tags: django, django-models, orm, django-templates, django-orm

Models:

```
class House(Model)

class Flat(Model):
    house = ForeignKey(House, related_name="houses")
    owner = ForeignKey(User)

class User(Model)
```

queryset:

```
queryset = User.objects.prefetch_related(
    Prefetch("flats", queryset=Flat.objects.select_related("houses"))
```

And then flats:

```
{% for flat in user.flats.all %}
<p>№ {{ flat.number }}, {{ flat.house.name }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

It's fine. But for houses I need only unique ones

```
{% for flat in user.flats.all %}
<p>House {{ flat.house.name }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

But this template gives me ALL houses, with duplicates.
How can I avoid duplicates, any ideas? I tried .distinct() but it's dosen't work, looks like I using distinct() wrong or etc.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you may end up with duplicate houses if a user is the `owner` of multiple `flat`s, which are all in the same `house`. To get all houses that the user is related to via `Flat`s, you can use a different query, starting with `House` so that you can use `distinct`:

```py
distinct_houses = House.objects.filter(flats__owner=user).distinct()
```

The above returns one House object for each flat where the user is an owner, and makes sure you don't have duplicates. (Note that the above assumes the `related_name` is changed to `flats` for `house = ForeignKey(House, related_name="flats")`, since "houses" as the related_name seems like a typo to relate back to the `Flat` model.)

Alternatively, you could do something in-memory in Python, if you still *also* need to know all `Flat`s via your original `queryset = User.objects.prefetch_related(...)` and don't want an additional query. Like:

```py
distinct_houses = {flat.house for flat in user.flats.all()}
```

Side note: it looks like you have a typo in needing to use `Flat.objects.select_related('house')` rather than `Flat.objects.select_related('houses')` based on the Foreign Key field name being `house`.

Comment: But the problem is that i need User query with All flats and Unique houses for every user.

Answer (score 0):

Only found solution with template filters.
Queryset:

```
queryset = User.objects.filter(status="ACTIVE").prefetch_related(
        Prefetch("flats", queryset=Flat.objects.select_related("house"))
    )
```

With this I can get all flats for each user:

```
{% for user in object_list %}
    {% for flat in user.flats.all %}
        {{ flat.number }}, {{ flat.house.name }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

And I am using template filter to get unique houses.

```
{% for user in object_list %}
    {% for flat in user.flats.all|get_unique_houses %}
        {{ flat.house.name }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}

# extra_tags.py
@register.filter(name="get_unique_houses")
def get_unique_houses(value):
    return value.distinct('house')
```